# overriding glibc crash

Tags: c, stack-trace, glibc

So when glibc crashes, it has a ***glibc detected *** crash message. It then prints a bunch of backtraces, like

```
*** glibc detected *** ./odin: free(): invalid pointer: 0xbfba4444 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x6b161)[0xb75f9161]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x6c9b8)[0xb75fa9b8]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6d)[0xb75fda9d]
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x1f)[0xb77da2ef]
```

All well and good, but other cases when things crash, I've been doing backtrace() and then using a system call to addr2line and printing the actual points in the function instead. But when it's a glibc crash, it quits bypassing any signal handlers I called.

Is there a way to hook against these glibc crashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an option for memory functions, you can toggle it using [`mallopt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallopt.3.html). By the sounds of it you want to set `M_CHECK_ACTION` to zero to allow execution to continue, unless you want the program to exit straight away in which case see if `2` allows you to do what you want.

This small program produces the normal glibc error: [test1.c](http://ideone.com/wfgsT)
This one ignores the error and carries on: [test2.c](http://ideone.com/RFB46)
This one aborts on the error: [test3.c](http://ideone.com/lRlA0)

Answer (score 3):

IIRC, glibc actually invokes `abort()`, so handling `SIGABRT` and printing a backtrace from that should give you the information you need.

However, I'd suggest trying valgrind: the message you're getting suggests that you have a memory corruption problem.

Side comment (sorry if this is redundant ;-)): core dumps are sometimes more useful that just backtraces. They can be enabled by e.g. setting `ulimit -c unlimited` in bash. When the program crashes it will produce a file named `core.` (or just `core` -- this depends on the system you're running; if your system runs abrtd core files are put into `/var/cache/abrt` if I'm not mistaken). Then you can inspect core files using gdb by running `gdb -c core a.out`; the gdb session will look like as if the process just have crashed.

Comment: Hmm, my program have had signal(SIGABRT, blah) for quite a while, and they didn't trigger (they would have printed a bunch of stuff) **Edit**: they actually did trigger, I just didn't see it. I will try valgrind as well, but the times I did somehow nothing was ever caught.